# Xcode 10.2 Use of undeclared identifier error when accessing FrameworkSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have just upgraded from MacOS Sierra to Mojave and from Xcode 10.1 to 10.2

Exactly same app (given in a zip) builds on a MacOS Mohave machine in Xcode 10.2 but it doesn't build on mine machine.

I tried restart, removing derived data etc:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyFrameworkSDK/MyFrameworkSDK-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *applicationId = [[NSString alloc] init];
    applicationId = [MyFrameworkSDK exposedMethod]; // here the error is triggered: Use of undeclared identifier 'MyFrameworkSDK'
    printf("%s", applicationId);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@end
```

Framework has been imported correctly, included in Linked frameworks and libraries, Bitcode is set to No, Frameworks path set etc, I repeat: it's exactly same project that on another machine works.

I tried even a re-install of Xcode. It didn't work.

Question:

What can be the cause of this? Other local cache, Xcode issues, any privacy set for framework not to be public?

I lost about 1 day with this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

It seems there might be some privacy limitations set for framework, the person that is able to access it is in the development team of the framework. If he changes Xcode team to none or another team same error shows up on that machine too.

Comment: In my experience this happened if the MyFrameworkSDK (Swift?) class is not compatible with objc for one reason or another. If that is the case, it will not export that class into the generated MyFrameworkSDK-Swift.h header. Find out what is the difference there (class declaration difference and the header difference, Swift compiler version difference).